# PHP ldap_read() no such object

Tags: php, ldap

I can successfully bind to ldap using `ldap_bind()`.

But when I come to do an `ldap_read()` using the Distinguished Name (DN) that I bound with, I get the error

> No such object

For example

```php
if (ldap_bind($ldap, $dn, $password))
{
  ldap_read($ldap, $dn, '(objectclass=*)');
}
else
{
  echo "Bind failed";
}
```

No matter what I try as a filter, I always get this error.

Comment: How do you know that your ldap_bind was successfull? After all it could be that you are not even connected and therefore the call doesn't work...

Comment: Because `ldap_bind()` returns true.  I've now edited the code in the original post to make this clear.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem.  It turned out to be a permissions problem in the directory.  The user didn't have read permission, even for their own entry.